# Wordpress related category function not sticking to single blog category of page

Tags: wordpress

The function below is working but it is pulling in all categories. I want it to just pull in the posts only related to the category of the single post it is on.

Here is the function:

function example_cats_related_post() {

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$cat_ids = array();
$categories = get_the_category( $post_id );

if(!empty($categories) && is_wp_error($categories)):
    foreach ($categories as $category):
        array_push($cat_ids, $category->term_id);
    endforeach;
endif;

$current_post_type = get_the_category($categories);
$query_args = array( 
    'category__in'   => $cat_ids,
    'post_type'      => get_the_category($categories),
    'post__not_in'    => array($post_id),
    'posts_per_page'  => '3'
 );

$related_cats_post = new WP_Query( $query_args );

if($related_cats_post->have_posts()):
     while($related_cats_post->have_posts()): $related_cats_post->the_post(); ?>
        <ul>
            <li>
                
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <div class="postCont">
                <div class="catTime">
                    <?php $categories = get_the_category();
                        if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
                            echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );  
                    } ?><span>|</span>
                     <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
                </div><br>
                    <div class="catTitle">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a></div><br>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <?php endwhile;

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
 endif;
}
```

Comment: You have problem at line $cat_ids = array(); actually, you are providibg empty array.

Comment: Even if I negate the empty array the result is the same. So it is not related. The empty is only if there are no post matching the category.

Comment: I figured it out. I did follow your advice and removed the empty array but that was not the issue. I was not calling the post id in the loop.

      <?php $categories = get_the_category($post_id);
       if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );